# Sort Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int, int, string, int>> By element of the Tuple

Tags: c#

I have a `Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, string, int, bool>>` object and I would like to know how I can sort the elements in the Dictionary by the third element of the Tuple Value (I mean the second "int" in `Tuple<int, string, int, bool>>`).

Comment: You can't sort a `Dictionary<,>` at all. You can get the elements ordered in a particular way, as a sequence - but it won't be a dictionary any more.

Comment: If you're sure a sorted dictionary is what you need, then you may want to consider using an [`OrderedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @IanH.: It's perfectly reasonable to have a `Dictionary` with an `int` key... what makes you think it isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't sort a dictionary, and that would be pointless since it defeats the purpose of a dictionary (sorting breaks the hash table).

You can get the items from the dictionary and sort them, like this:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, Tuple<int, string, int, bool>> list;
list = dict.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value.Item3).ToList();
```

As you see, the end result is a list, not a dictionary.

Comment: This seems good, but isn't it: ``List<KeyValuePair<int, Tuple<int, string, int, bool>>> list;temp.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value.Item3).ToList();``??

Comment: Ah yes, typo. Thanks @Kikus

Comment: I was looking for info and I found this question and I would like to comment that is possible to sort a dictionary and I think it is not pointless depending on what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid some of the extra memory allocations by converting to list or array and sorting in-place:

```
var arr = dic.ToArray();
Array.Sort(arr, (a, b) => a.Value.Item3.CompareTo(b.Value.Item3));
```

Comment: You mean `OrderBy` vs `Array.Sort` ?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Yes, the point is that the `.OrderBy` LINQ extension returns `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` collection that doesn't implement `ICollection<T>` (no `.Count`), so `.ToList` or `.ToArray` would make multiple memory allocations

Answer (score 0):

I think this is too late for you but if someone still looking for this kind of info, this is the way I would sort this

```
var myDict = from entry in yourDictionary orderby entry.Value.Item3 descending select entry;
```

This would sort the dictionary taking the third value of the `Tuple` in descending way, you can use `ascending` instead of `descending` if it is what you are looking for, hope this can help someone